# Undecorated Frame with header line as titlebar

Tags: frames, header-line

I am trying to remove all window manager decorations from emacs. This works well using:

```
(set-frame-parameter nil 'undecorated t)
```

But now what I want to have is a one line (global) header line (which spans across the entire frame) which acts like a title bar. Where I can drag the frame and resize it and so on.

```
(set-frame-parameter nil 'drag-with-header-line t)
```

Works to make the header line draggable. But I so far was only able to get a separate header line for each window. But I want one global one. Also I did not find out a way to resize the frame.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, a header-line, like a mode-line, is specific to a particular buffer, which means a window showing that buffer.

So I believe the answer is that you can't do what you want, without having just one window in the frame.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make a titlebar that works as you want, but you can drag the window around by clicking anywhere on it and holding down the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (this works on Linux). As for resizing the frame, you need to set the frame parameters `drag-internal-border` and `internal-border-width`, for instance

```
(setq default-frame-alist
      (append ;                        Note: if there are any conflicting settings in ‘default-frame-alist’, it is the one that comes first that gets applied.
       '((undecorated . t)
         (drag-internal-border . t)
         (internal-border-width . 4))
       default-frame-alist))
```

Or, interactively, you can use the commands `set-frame-height` and `set-frame-width` (assuming you're on Emacs 27).